# Sending messages from Java to RabbitMQ using com.rabbitmq.http.client.Client

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to send messages from a Java service to RabbitMQ.

I'm using some Java RabbitMQ client library and trying to run the following code:

```
    private static Client setAcceptAllSSL() throws Exception {
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (cert, authType) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
        requestFactory = new HttpComponentsRestTemplateConfigurator(sslsf,sslContext);
        return new Client(new ClientParameters().url(url).username(username).password(password).restTemplateConfigurator(requestFactory));
    }
```

In the last line (Client objectinitialization), the following error is thrown:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder

I think I might be missing something in my pom.xml or maybe something with the version of Spring. However, I have not been able to find any missing import/library/version issues.

Please help :)

Comment: For me, this method throws ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory.

Comment: Do you have this? <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
</dependency>

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this jackson dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
</dependency>
```